# how to use SFINAE to return (const_)iterator from end() method

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I wanted to create a collection wrapper where `end` method would be exposed from a member. The collection itself may or may not be `const` so I can't distinguish `const_iterator` and `iterator` based on it, but the inner collection (template) defines the constness. I thought using `enable_if<is_const<T` will make that happen but seems not. Thanks for you help

```
#include <cassert>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename ITEMS>
struct collection {
    ITEMS& _items;

    collection(ITEMS& items) : _items(items) {
    }

    auto find(int i) const {
        return std::find(_items.begin(), _items.end(), i);
    }

    typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_const<ITEMS>::value>::const_iterator
    end() const {
        return _items.end();
    }

    typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_const<ITEMS>::value>::iterator
    end() const {
        return _items.end();
    }
};

template <typename ITEMS>
collection<ITEMS>
make_collection(ITEMS& items) {
    return collection<ITEMS>(items);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> ints = {1, 2, 3};
    auto col = make_collection(ints);                                                                                                
    const auto it = col.find(3);                                                                                                     
    assert(it != col.end());                                                                                                         

    const auto cints = ints;                                                                                                         
    auto ccol = make_collection(cints);                                                                                              
    const auto cit = ccol.find(3);                                                                                                   
    assert(cit != ccol.end());                                                                                                       

    return 0;                                                                                                                        
}
```

edit: using just `auto end() const { return _items.end(); }` works, but I'd like to understand why the templating magic doesn't.

Comment: Just use `auto` or `decltype`.

Comment: that's true, it works, I wanted to more understand why this templating magic doesn't work

Comment: Uhh, `std::enable_if_t<std::is_const<ITEMS>::value>` is either `void` or invalid. `typename void::const_iterator` makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code. Firstly, `std::enable_if_t` will either be invalid, or resolve to a type. If you don't specify which type the default is void. In your examples you are not specifying a type.

The second problem is that the member functions depend on the class template. All the code inside a template must be valid when instatiated. When you instantiate `collection` with a `cont` container, the non-const overload will fail to deduce the return type. But it's still a part of the class template, and if a part of it fails the compiler will not ignore that part, but it will give a compilation error.

The way to solve that is to make both the `end` methods template methods and tranfer the template parameter from the class. This way the `end` method is not instatiated until called, and if one fails, it's ok as long as the other one works.

```
template <typename ITEMS>
struct collection {
    ITEMS& _items;

    collection(ITEMS& items) : _items(items) {
    }

    auto find(int i) const {
        return std::find(_items.begin(), _items.end(), i);
    }

    template <typename T = ITEMS>
    typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_const<T>::value, T>::const_iterator
    end() const {
        return _items.end();
    }

    template <typename T = ITEMS>
    typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_const<T>::value, T>::iterator
    end() const {
        return _items.end();
    }
};
```